# What is the formal definition of the quotient space $D_n/ \partial D_n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I've encountered the following statement:
"..This is equivalent to regarding $S_n$ as the quotient space $D_n/ \partial D_n$".

I'm familiar with the notion of $X/ \sim$ given an equivalence relation $\sim$, but I'm not sure what the equivalence relation is when given another space instead of $\sim$, as in $D_n/ \partial D_n$. Is this shorthand for some implicit equivalence relation that I'm missing?

Comment: Two elements are equivalent if they both lie in $\partial D_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a topological space and $A\subseteq X$ a subset, one writes $X/A$ for the quotient space $X/\sim_A$ (equipped with the quotient topology), where $\sim_A$ is the equivalence relation generated by $a\sim a^{\prime}$ for all $a,a^{\prime}\in A$. To be explicit, the equivalence classes of this equivalence relation are $\{x\}$ for all $x\in X-A$ and $A$ itself. Geometrically, passing from $X$ to $X/A$ has the effect of "collapsing $A$ to a point". (For the sake of completeness, I will mention that $X/\emptyset$ is, by convention, the disjoint union of $X$ and a singleton.)